# Compilation error: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)*

Tags: visual-studio-code, elm

When I attempt to compile the Main.elm file (via Ctrl+F5) using Visual Studio Code, I receive the following error:

**Error:**
*elm-make: c:\Users\Bizmonger\Documents\Visual: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)*

**Note:**

I am trying to compile an [Elm solution that I cloned from GitHub](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example).

Here's the parent directory:
[image]

Here's the src directory with the elm files:

[image]

Why am I receiving this error?

[image]

Comment: The error message looks like it truncates the folder name after `Visual`, but I'm assuming you're in a folder called something like `Visual Studio Projects`. Try moving the project to a folder tree without a space in the name.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message looks like it truncates the folder name after `Visual`, but I'm assuming you're in a folder called something like `Visual Studio Projects`. Try moving the project to a folder tree without a space in the name.